# How to send test events to Azure Event Grid Domain

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventgrid

I have provisioned Azure Event Grid domain in the portal and created a couple of Domain Topics under the hood. Also, a service bus queue has been configured as an endpoint to receive those events.

Now, I just want to send a few sample events to the Azure Event Grid Domain. How do I go about it? is there any tool available to send the events out of the box?

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, any REST Client tool can be used for posting an event to the AEG domain or you can try my [Azure Event Grid Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1254463/Azure-Event-Grid-Tester):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Roman. While I am using an online Rest client I am getting the following error: {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unexpected token when reading JSON. Expected: StartArray, actual: StartObject. ",
        "details": [{
            "code": "InputJsonInvalid",
            "message": "Unexpected token when reading JSON. Expected: StartArray, actual: StartObject."
        }]
    }
}
Json payload used for testing:
{
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  }
}

Comment: the input schema for your event domain endpoint required an array: [ { "object": { "a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f" } } ] , see my picture.

Comment: Now, I am getting the below error ;) {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "The event time property 'eventTime' was not a valid date/time. ",
        "details": [{
            "code": "InputJsonInvalid",
            "message": "The event time property 'eventTime' was not a valid date/time. "
        }]
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling for examples...
3 tricks that were not obvious at first when using Postman

- add the header aeg-sas-key if you want the easy way.  (extra work if you want it - generate your own sas key and provide it as aeg-sas-token).
- Make sure content type is application/cloudevents+json; charset=utf-8
- while you post it to the endpoint for your event domain ...in the cloudevent data body, the **source** should be set to the **topic name** (no uri - just the raw name that you added as a domain topic under your eventgrid domain).

[image]

[image]